# How to use spaces in Python with .isalpha()

Tags: python

I am currently learning **Python** with Codecademy, and they have a project there called "PygLatin translator". I have made the same thing from scratch(to test my knowledge) and it works, but only *1 word at a time.* 
Due to it using the .isalpha() function, if you put spaces inside the input box, it says that it is not allowed(as spaces are not alphabetical characters).
For example:
Python --> ythonPay
Python is Cool --> rejected
Are there currently any ways to fix this?
Also, 1 more thing: I am using Python version 2.7.3, because I read somewhere that it is more noob-friendly.
This is my code:

```
pyg = "ay"
print "Welcome to the English --> (really weak) Encrypter!"
name = raw_input("Enter a word. ")
if len(name) > 0 and name.isalpha():
word = name.lower()
first = name[0]
new_word = word[1:] + first + pyg
print new_word
elif len(name) == 0:
print "You haven't typed in anything."
else:
print "You can only use alphabetical characters. No spaces, I am working on that."
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste what you've tried even if it's wrong ?

Comment: Python 2 is no more noob friendly than Python 3. Python 3 has in fact clearer error modes. Is this 'somewhere' perhaps the writings by Zed Shaw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes: use the [built-in string methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).  Use the split method to break the input into individual words.  Translate each individually.  Paste them back together with the join method.  For instance:

```
text = input( ... )
word_list = text.split()
# Translate each word individually.
pig_latin = ' '.join(translated_word_list)
```

Does that get you moving?